Is this proof correct? [(all propositions are true)->(no contradictions)]
Is this proof correct?

There is no proof that the axiom is true

Therefore, there is no "Proof by contradiction"

Therefore, if the axiom is denied, there is no contradiction


Three Axioms of Logic

Law of Identity (A=A)

Law of Noncontradiction (not(p and not p))

Law of the Excluded Middle (not p or p)


deny Law of Identity

[deny (A=A)]<->[(A=/=A) is true]

[(A=/=A) is true]->No contradiction


deny Law of Noncontradiction

[deny (not(p and not p))]<->[(p and not p) is true]

[(p and not p) is true]->No contradiction

[(p and not p) is true]<->[All propositions are true]

[All propositions are true]->No contradiction


no contradiction means "logically possible"

I don't see any question here, just an attempt to push a personal philosophy.

For the record, I've flagged this question as "very low quality" question that is unsalvageable.

There is nothing to prove: a contradiction is obviously false and the antecedent "ALL propositions are True" means the same as "There are NO propositions that are NOT True".

@MauroALLEGRANZA "Are you saying that since there are no false propositions, contradictions can't be false either, and thus contradictions disappear?"

No. You are asserting: "All propositions are True".

@MauroALLEGRANZA Please tell me why that is wrong

Proof :)

If all propositions are true then there are no false propositions
If there are no false propositions there can be no contradictions
All propositions are true
If all propositions are true there can be no contradictions [1, 2 HS]
There can be no contradictions [4, 5 MP]

